# What is the proper permission settings to create a moderated, private organic group (in commons 3)?

Tags: organic-groups, 7

I'm trying to create a private group in Drupal Commons. It is my assumption that one follows open, public groups.

However, I've marked a few groups as private using the default roles and permissions. I anticipated seeing a *Register* option for that group.

I guess I'm trying to create a moderated group where the user is approved by the group owner. How does this happen?

I'm also seeing that Commons Groups may be interfering with the group permissions by graying out the *Member subscribe only* with the approval option ([drupal ticket link](https://drupal.org/node/1971074?mode=2&sort=2)).

[image]

In the group field settings, I have the following fields attached to groups and content types.

> [image]

> [image: enter code here]

The group settings for one example group I wish to make private are the following.

> [image]

However, while masquerading as authenticated user, I still see the *Follow* button. I would expect to see a *Register for this group* option.

Answer (score 1):

I understand your confusion. In Drupal Commons, follow is not the same as registering as a group member.

If you check off the non-member checkbox on the Subscribe to group line then non-members can apply to register for that group. AS you have your other settings then an administrator can approve this registration.

Becoming a member of a group allows you to post. However, in the default configuration, posts in even private groups are visible unless additional permissions are applied and users may still follow the group.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've checked this item for non-members (to subscribe via approval). However, when logged in as a test user, I still see *follow* and not register.

Comment: There should be a link for Join Group under the heading "Moderated group". You should also have selected "Joining requires admin approval" under Privacy settings. The follow option will still show.